# Mitigation for imblearn pipelines

Tags: python, data-science, imblearn, fairlearn

I'm trying to mitigate unfairness for a model I trained using an imblearn pipeline with ADASYN. My pipeline looks like this:

```
loaded_model = Pipeline(steps=[('feature_scaler', StandardScaler()), 
                ('adasyn_resampling', ADASYN(random_state=123), 
                ('low_variance_remover', VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.01)), 
                ('feature_selection', SelectFromModel(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0), max_features=35)), 
                ('classifier', CalibratedClassifierCV(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=0.1, penalty='l1', random_state=0, solver='saga'), method='isotonic'))])
```

When I try to run the ExponentiatedGradient:

```
from fairlearn.reductions import EqualizedOdds, ExponentiatedGradient

exponentiated_gradient = ExponentiatedGradient(
    estimator=loaded_model,
    constraints=EqualizedOdds(difference_bound=0.01), 
    sample_weight_name="classifier__sample_weight")

exponentiated_gradient.fit(X_train.drop(columns=['PCa-ID']), y_train, sensitive_features=sf_train)
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_2882607/3174663212.py in <module>
     32     sample_weight_name="classifier__sample_weight")
     33 
---> 34 exponentiated_gradient.fit(X_train.drop(columns=['PCa-ID']), y_train, sensitive_features=sf_train)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fairlearn/reductions/_exponentiated_gradient/exponentiated_gradient.py in fit(self, X, y, **kwargs)
    166 
    167             # select classifier according to best_h method
--> 168             h, h_idx = lagrangian.best_h(lambda_vec)
    169 
    170             if t == 0:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fairlearn/reductions/_exponentiated_gradient/_lagrangian.py in best_h(self, lambda_vec)
    232         the vector of Lagrange multipliers `lambda_vec`.
    233         """
--> 234         classifier = self._call_oracle(lambda_vec)
    235 
    236         def h(X):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fairlearn/reductions/_exponentiated_gradient/_lagrangian.py in _call_oracle(self, lambda_vec)
    220 
    221         oracle_call_start_time = time()
--> 222         estimator.fit(self.constraints.X, redY, **{self.sample_weight_name: redW})
    223         self.oracle_execution_times.append(time() - oracle_call_start_time)
    224         self.n_oracle_calls += 1

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imblearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    295             if self._final_estimator != "passthrough":
    296                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 297                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, yt, **fit_params_last_step)
    298         return self
    299 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/calibration.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    269         X, y = indexable(X, y)
    270         if sample_weight is not None:
--> 271             sample_weight = _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X)
    272 
    273         if self.base_estimator is None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in _check_sample_weight(sample_weight, X, dtype, copy)
   1563 
   1564         if sample_weight.shape != (n_samples,):
-> 1565             raise ValueError(
   1566                 "sample_weight.shape == {}, expected {}!".format(
   1567                     sample_weight.shape, (n_samples,)

ValueError: sample_weight.shape == (4834,), expected (6967,)!
```

I imagine this is due to the resampling step. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please always provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Hi! Here's the full error traceback:

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the resampling doesn't play well with `ExponentiatedGradient`: its reweightings are determined as they would be applied to `X`, but that has changed shape before reaching the `classifier` step.

Since the weights will only affect the `classifier` step anyway, I suspect you could just wrap that directly with the exponentiated gradient, inside the pipeline. But I'm not very familiar with `fairlearn` or `ExponentiatedGradient`.